# My 'cleaner' code runs slower than the macro recorded version

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm experiencing a strange issue with a spreadsheet that has tons of calculations and also has to run a few of goal seeks.

It's not my spreadsheet - it belongs to another team - but I have to use it a lot, and it's slow. Slow enough to be annoying. So I'm trying to speed it up, then I'll get the other team to switch to my faster code.

The problem is, my rewritten code is running twice as slow as the original macro recorded code and I can't tell why.

The original code:

```
Range("P43").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("P35").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlSubtract, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("P43").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("P35")

Range("Q43").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("Q35").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlSubtract, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("Q43").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("Q35")

...
```

It repeats this block of code for each column until it reaches column Z, so it's pretty lengthy.

When I was looking at this I thought speeding it up would be easy - get rid of the selects, add a loop, turn off screen updating, etc - the usual.

This is my rewritten code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'our worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis")

'column nos start with c; row nos with r
Dim cFirst As Integer, cLast As Integer, cCurrent As Integer
Dim rGoal As Integer, rChange As Integer

cFirst = 16 'col P
cLast = 26 'col Z

rGoal = 43
rChange = 35

With ws
    For cCurrent = cFirst To cLast
        'copy values from current column to last column to the other row
        .Range(.Cells(rChange, cCurrent), .Cells(rChange, cLast)).Value = .Range(.Cells(rGoal, cCurrent), .Cells(rGoal, cLast)).Value
        'run the goal seek on the current column
        .Cells(rGoal, cCurrent).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Cells(rChange, cCurrent)
    Next cCurrent
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Have I done something obviously wrong? I just can't see it. My new code is much shorter and produces exactly the same results but takes double the time...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This might be a better fit at [codereview.se]

Comment: Thanks John, will try there if nothing pans out here!

Comment: Code Review would be better. But a first guess is the myriad of `.Range`/`.Cells` calls - resolving all these range objects is probably the culprit.

Comment: There seems to be a subtraction effect in the recorded macro code paste Function, but you haven't? Does this double the goal seek time perhaps? `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlSubtract,`

Answer (score 1):

As [MacroMarc astutely pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412842/my-cleaner-code-runs-slower-than-the-macro-recorded-version#comment89814059_51412842), I wasn't quite replicating the original recorded code - can't believe I couldn't see it!

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, *>>*Operation:=xlSubtract*<<*, _
   ...
```

Without this operation the refactored code introduced a bug that made the `GoalSeek` call work much harder than it was supposed to. The assignment should implement this `xlSubtract` operation:

```
.Range(.Cells(rChange, cCurrent), .Cells(rChange, cLast)) _
.Value = .Range(.Cells(rChange, cCurrent), .Cells(rChange, cLast)).Value _
       - .Range(.Cells(rGoal, cCurrent), .Cells(rGoal, cLast)).Value
```

Comment: You can't accept a comment as an answer, because...well, it's a comment and not an answer. :-) @MacroMarc should turn that comment into an answer instead.

Comment: @KenWhite salvaged :)